# React Component not Rendering Updated State from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

What is the correct place to load data in react?

According to the docs, the `componentDidMount` is the recommended place but it is run after rendering which appears to be a silly place to load data. Indeed my experiment below shows the data/state is never rendered. Only if data is loaded in `componentWillMount` do I see the results.

Example: In the following https://jsfiddle.net/sf9n7zj1/3/ the list of `toDos` is initially one item `['One']` and should subsequently load 2 more items to become `['One', 'Two', 'Three']`. This happens correctly as is shown in the state but is never rendered and the UI only shows `One`.

[image: todo list with one item only]

Clicking on the "ToDos" `<h2>` tag in the fiddle will log the component state and there we see (in the developer console) that the 3 toDos and foo=1 are correctly set in state. Why is this never rendered?

[image: console log]

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: 0,
      toDos: ['One']
    }
    this.updateFoo = () => {
      console.log("updateFoo", this.state)
      this.setState((state) => {
        state.foo = 1;
      })
    }
  }
  // componentWillMount() {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((state) => {
      state.toDos = [...state.toDos, 'Two', 'Three']
    })
    console.log("Loaded ToDos...", this.state);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={this.updateFoo}>ToDos {this.state.foo}</h2>
        <ul>
          {this.state.toDos.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<TodoApp />);
```

Note:

- Moving the data loading to the (deprecated) `componentWillMount` causes everything to work but the [react blog](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) themselves recommend loading data in `componentDidMount`
- Clicking sets state.foo to `1` but this too, is not rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a symptom of a different issue - state mutation.

In both `setState` calls in the sample code you are mutating state `state.toDos =`. This will cause missed re-renders, which is why it appears that `componentWillMount` is working correctly but `componentDidMount` isn't.

Since `componentWillMount` runs before the first render, the state is "updated" (mutated) before it's used the first time. With `componentDidMount` the state is updated after the render. This would normally just trigger a re-render and you'd see your correct value near instantly. But the mutation causes that re-render to be skipped.

You can correct your state updates to be non-mutating with something like:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  toDos: [
    ...state.toDos, 
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ]
}))
```

Regarding *but it is run after rendering which appears to be a silly place to load data*, it may seem that way, but in reality the docs are correct. An additional render isn't a problem, and most real world data loading scenarios are asynchronous, so regardless of the lifecycle method used to trigger it, it's going to need to re-render.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "mutate" and why this is bad?

In your example you effectively clobber the entire state. For that reason I chose to update only the single property with `state.toDos = ...`. Following your lead I would need to completely re-construct my state (with possibly dozens of unrelated properties) just to update one property.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening, and it's required for React to work properly. In this section of the docs, it shows this simple example (https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) - your code is doing the same thing, just from within the updater callback function.

Comment: In class based components like this one, the setState function merges the new state object passed into the previous state object. That's why you don't need to specify `toDos` when updating `foo`. But the object ultimately used to update state is completely new. In function based components using the `useState` hooks, this merge is actually removed and you must re-create the a state object completely yourself.

Comment: React determines whether it should re-render or not by checking for simple object equality `newState == oldState`. Mutating state means both newState and oldState will reference the same object, so React doesn't know it should re-render. This is ultimately why mutation is bad. Replacing the state object creates a new object reference and React will re-render correctly

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. How frustrating for beginners used to frameworks (like Vue) which explicitly don't work when you clobber state objects. Someone should invent a framework which doesn't need these shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

You're not replacing state, you're *mutating* state:

```
state.toDos = [...state.toDos, 'Two', 'Three']
```

So React doesn't see that an update has been made.  In the state setting operation, don't change properties on the state object.  Return a new object to reflect the updated state.  For example:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  toDos: [...state.toDos, 'Two', 'Three']
}))
```

And:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  foo: 1
}))
```

*Note the additional parentheses around the curly braces, indicating that this function is a single expression returning an object rather than a block of code.*